# quick linux question

Tags: linux, batch-processing

I'm trying to do the following:

$OOOPYTHON DocumentConverter.py .odt .pdf

for all of the ODT files i have in a particular document and looking for the right syntax to convert all odts to pdfs.

Thanks!
Jake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *.odt; do
    $OOOPYTHON DocumentConverter.py "$file" "${file%.odt}.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find, ex :

```
find /path/to/files/ -name '*.odt' -exec python /path/to/DocumentConverter.py '{}' '{}.pdf' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in `ls *.odt`
do
   DocumentConverter.py $file ${file%.odt}.pdf
done
```

or whatever the actual command syntax is

Comment: great, so i did this:

for file in `ls *.odt`
do
   $OOOPYTHON DocumentConverter.py $file $file.pdf
done

but how do i get the input file "123.odt" not to convert to "123.odt.pdf" with the above code?